# Facebook page name change notification to installed application

Tags: php, facebook

i have a facebook page application, the user can install my application to their pages using add page tab option. i will get the manage_pages permission when they installed my application .

Now i will collect the page information at the time of installation and store the values to my database.

1. If the user is trying to edit the page name or any other information after the application installation . This case what i have stored in my database and the live page details will be different.

   - does facabook provide any option to notify the application owners that this page is update (so that i can run a script to get it update)  ?
   - or do i need to have scheduler script to keep check the fb details ?

i want to keep sync the real time data when the user update the page information.

for example.
before installing the application:

- user page name will be : page1

after the installation i will get the page information and store it to my database:

- no in my db i have the value "page1"

later user changes his page name to : page 2

- in this case my db will have the value "page1", but it should be "page2"

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance..